# Django orm filling out 3 interrelated forms on one page and passing each other last inserted id. Issue if form 2 o 3 fail. Form 1 stays childless

Tags: django, orm

I have come across an interesting issue (probably because of my lack of knowledge):
I have 3 tables (3 forms) that are interrelated. Address, property and photos.
The first table or form is Address, it is populated by using a select list. So, on clicking the submit button, that first form will populate a row in Address table. Then I obtain that last id in order to pass it to form 2, properties and the properties will pass the last id inserted to photos, so the three are related by Foreign Keys.
What happens in this scheme?
If the Property form fails because someone enters bad input in a text field, the model will reject it and will return the user back to the form. BUT, notice that the row in table address was already inserted and it will stay there. Yes, you may say that I could include a line of code in the processing of form Properties, that if it fails, it should delete the recently address row inserted but that doesn't help me because the id sequence will not be reset in the table, it will leap to the next one leaving a gap in the id series, 1,2,4 (if I deleted row 3). This would not affect the processing but I don't like this, I would rather have id address = 1 and id property = 1 correlated.
I know there is a thing called commit(false) but that can't help because that does not insert a row in the table, whereby I can't get the id that I need to pass to the property table,